# Updating big tables with string replace runs into ORA-30036: unable to extend segment

Tags: oracle, sql-update, batch-processing

Updating big tables with string replace runs into ORA-30036: unable to extend segment

The table is like (with an Index on ID):

```
CREATE TABLE "DB"."C_DATA" 
(   
        "ID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "KEY" VARCHAR2(512 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "VALUE" CLOB, 
    "UNIQUE_ID" VARCHAR2(512 CHAR), 
    "DT_CREATE" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT sysdate, 
    CONSTRAINT "C_DATA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

In the column VALUE are strings with varying length from some character up to some 1000 characters.
I have to update the column and replace some characters lets say replace comas with semicolons:

```
UPDATE DB.C_DATA tbl
   SET VALUE = REPLACE(tbl.VALUE, ',', ';')
   WHERE VALUE like '%,%';
```

With this I have now two problems:
1)  When I run this I run into the “ORA-30036: unable to extend segment …”
2)  For some values I have the feeling this does not work and not all characters are replaced correctly.

Add2: If I run on smaller data set I got the problem that for longer entries it seems to not do its job. Just like ignoring the replace. (is this related to the second problem?)

Add1: As soon as I test with the bigger dataset in the DB it fails like ORA-30036  (not even to think about the full dataset (50.000.000 rows))
It is clear that the table space could be increased but that is not really an option now, 
Would there be a way to tell the database to split this statement into smaller Jobs and execute them after each other to not have the full set into the undo space?
Not having this executed/applied at once would not be an issue (as long is it finishes in an finite time).
If this is not doable within an oracle SQL statement / PLSQL – what (scriptable) approach would be possible?